# Symfony3 FormBuilder with associative array

Tags: php, forms, symfony, collections, symfony-3.4

In advance, sorry for my english...

I have a problem with my symfony form which seem simple but i don't understand how to do.

I have a user class which has an argument "salaries". This is an array of object "salary" with an id, a label and an amount.

When i add a user, i want to fill my objects "salary". I want for each instance of salary a widget with the label (which is in my object salary) and the input to put the amount.

I tried with collectionType but it doesn't seem to work.
I tried to create a field in my object user per salary but i can't create the setter and getter dynamically.

Just for information, i don't use Doctrine.

If it's not clear, i can explain in French, it will be better...

Here's my userType.php :

```
$builder
->add('name', TextType::class, array('label'=>'Name : '))
->add('lastname', TextType::class, array('label'=>'Lastname : '))
->add('salaries', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => salaryType::class));
```

My salaryType.php :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){

        $builder->add('amount', TextType::class, array('label'=> $builder->getData()->getLabel(), 'required' => false));
        $builder->getForm();
}
```

And my twig :

```
<div id="infos">
    <div class="title">Salary</div>
        <div>
        {% for salary in formUser.salaries %}
            <div><span>{{ form_label(salary.label) }}</span><span>{{ form_widget(salary.amount) }}</span></div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your userType replace this

```
   ->add('salaries', CollectionType::class, array('entry_type' => 
 salaryType::class));
```

By

```
$builder->add('salaries', EntityType::class, [
                    'class' => 'NameBundle:salary',
                    'empty_value' => 'Choise a Salary',
                    'label' => 'Salary',
                    'required' => false,
                    'query_builder' => function (SalaryRepository $er){
                        return $er->findAll();
                    }
                ]);
```

Comment: Thnaks for your answer but unfortunately i don't use Doctrine... so your method cannot match